# Get property class instance in property decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write a `@Prop` decorator to help me set custom elements attributes.

This is the code I'm trying to achieve:

```
class MyClass extends HtmlElement {
   get text() {
     return this.getAttribute('text')
   }

   set text(newVal){
     this.setAttribute('text', newVal)
   }

   connectedCallback() {
     this.innerHTML = `<div>${this.text}</div>`
   }
}
```

This is the class with decorator

```
class MyClass extends HtmlElement {
   @Prop() text: string;

   connectedCallback() {
     this.innerHTML = `<div>${this.text}</div>`
   }
}
```

This is the decorator function

```
const Prop = () => (target : any, key : string) => {
    const getter = () => target.getAttribute(key);
    const setter = (newVal) => target.setAttribute(key, newVal);

    if (!delete this[key]) return;
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter
    });
}
```

However whenever the getter function is invoked I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at HTMLElement.getter (app.js:16)
```

Checking out `app.js:16` reveals this line of code:

```
const getter = () => target.getAttribute(key);
```

with `target.getAttribute(key);` being underlined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Decorators are invoked on with the class as the target not an instance of the the class. The instance of the class will come in the getter /setter function as `this`. This is why using an arrow function is a bad idea here, as they capture `this` from declaration site. Using a regular function work best in this case.

```
const Prop = () => (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const getter = function (this: HTMLElement) {
        return this.getAttribute(key);
    }
    const setter = function (this: HTMLElement, newVal) {
        this.setAttribute(key, newVal);
    }
    descriptor = descriptor || {};
    descriptor.get = getter;
    descriptor.set = setter;
    return descriptor;
}

class MyClass extends HTMLElement {
    @Prop() text: string;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<div>${this.text}</div>`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! for class properties the `PropertyDescriptor` isn't passed in so modifying has to be done with `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: @Rodrigo while not passed in, I create it if it is undefined, and the decorator machinery will call `defineProperty` if a descriptor is returned. You should do it this way to allow composition of decorators (each decorator modifies the definition and the final result is registered, also your definition might get overridden). You should try the code, works as posted, I always test ;-)

Comment: When I try to compile with the third parameter present TypeScript throws me this error `Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.`

Comment: @Rodrigo I'm almost five years late to the party but the fix for that error is to use `TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>`

Answer (score 0):

To define getters and setter dont just remove the property and then re-add it but use the property descriptor

```
const Prop = () => (target : any, key : string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
  // Could be inlined...
  const getter = () => target.getAttribute(key);
  const setter = (newVal) => target.setAttribute(key, newVal);

  descriptor.set = setter
  descriptor.get = getter
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: Is the descriptor parameter passed in for property decorators or just method decorators?

Comment: Yes it is. Does this solve your problem or does it more have to do with: `target.getAttribute(key)`?

Comment: It has to do with `target.getAttribute(key)`. target seems to be just a prototype of the class and not an instance. Is there any way to get the instance?

Comment: I see... Are you sure the target does have a getAttribute method? Can you try to log it and confirm it does? Because I suspect the this context for the getter is changed somewhere

Comment: If I try to `console.log(target.getAttribute(key))` I get an `Illegal invocation` error. If I just `console.log(target)` and I view the attributes property the same error appears inside the array. `Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLElement.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)`

Comment: Can you try to: console.log(target, this) in the decorator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178821/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-patrick-hollweck).