# Defined property inside a JS decorator is not visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am trying to write a decorator that sets a value as the code below demonstrates

```
function setter(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    value: 'Hello world',
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
  });
}

class Test {
  @setter
  public key: string;
}

const instance = new Test();
console.log(instance.key);                // Outputs: 'Hello world'
console.log(JSON.stringify(instance));    // Outputs: '{}'
```

How come the JSON.stringify is not returning `{ key: 'Hello world' }` instead of `{}`?

I have tried to debug the issue further

```
function setter(target: any, propertyKey: string) {

  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    value: `Time -> ${new Date().getTime()}`,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
  });
}

class Test {
  @setter
  public key: string;
}

async function main() {
  // Create a promise to wait 2 seconds
  const wait = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
  });

  // Create a new instance
  const instance1 = new Test();
  // Wait
  await wait;
  // Create a second instance
  const instance2 = new Test();

  // Log the values of key in each instance
  console.log(instance1.key);  // Outputs 'Time -> 1624272363288'
  console.log(instance2.key);  // Outputs 'Time -> 1624272363288'
}

main();
```

How come the values are not unique? Has the key property been added the class (Protoype) level instead of the instance? Is decorating values is similar to creating a static value?

Comment: I don't think you can use `@setter` in that scenario. If you only log `instance` you will see, that an object `Test` is created, but no values are asigned

Comment: what is the definition of `class Test` in the second code?

Comment: @JaromandaX The same as above. I did not change it

Comment: Your `@setter` is decorating `Test.prototype.key`. The `instance` does not have an own `key` property, it is inherited, that's why it doesn't show up in the JSON.

Comment: the decorator is executed once, and adds the property to `Test.prototype`

Comment: @thedethfox - so how did the `instance1.key` magically become a Number, rather than the text 'Hello World'?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am so sorry. I have updated the setter's value to add time stamp instead of Hello world to see if it generates several unique values. That's why I asked if the value is assigned to the prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer to the question**

*How come the JSON.stringify is not returning { key: 'Hello world' } instead of {}?*

The decorated property is added to the prototype and therefore it does not appear in the result of JSON.stringify().

An example of this:

```
function setter(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    value: 'Hello world',
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
  });
}

class Test {
  @setter
  public key: string;
}

const instance = new Test();
console.log(instance.key);                    // Outputs: 'Hello world'
console.log(JSON.stringify(instance));        // Outputs: '{}'
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance)); // Outputs: "{ key: 'Hello world' }"
```

---

**How to get around this?**

1. We can add the `toJSON` method to the class like the example below demonstrates:

```
    function setter(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        value: 'Hello world',
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
      });
    }
    
    class Test {
      @setter
      public key: string;
    
      public a = 'A';
      public b = 'B';
    
      public toJSON() {
        return { a: this.a, b: this.b, key: Object.getPrototypeOf(instance).key };
      }
    }
    
    const instance = new Test();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(instance)); // Outputs: {"a":"A","b":"B","key":"Hello world"}
```

2. If the decorator is not required to be on the property level, then we can use a class decorator:

```
function setter(constructor) {
  return class extends constructor {
    key = 'update value';
    secret = 'set a new value';
  };
}

@setter
class Test {
  public key: string;
}

const instance = new Test();
console.log(JSON.stringify(instance));  
// Outputs: {"key":"update value","secret":"set a new value"
```

---

Notes about the **Property Descriptor**

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) clearly mentions the following:

> NOTE  A Property Descriptor is not provided as an argument to a property decorator due to how property decorators are initialized in TypeScript. This is because there is currently no mechanism to describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype, and no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property. The return value is ignored too. As such, a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property of a specific name has been declared for a class.

This means that the 3ed param is always undefined in our case. The code below illustrates that:

```
function setter(...args) {
  console.log(args);   // Outputs: [ TestArgs {}, 'key', undefined ]
}

class TestArgs {
  @setter
  public key: string;
}

const t = new TestArgs();
```

As you can see here above the 3ed parameters which is supposed to be the property descriptor is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030868/get-property-class-instance-in-property-decorator) and the [official TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), property decorators don't get access to the object instance, meaning, in your example, `target` is not an instance of the class.

Instead, you want to use the third parameter: the (maybe already existing) `descriptor` object, that allows you define getter and setter functions, which in turn can access `this` (I call it `self` in the code below):

```js
function setter(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  descriptor = descriptor || {};
  descriptor.get = function g(self: Test) { return self.x; };
  descriptor.set = function s(self: Test, value: any) { self.x = value; };
}
```

Also note that TS already has setters, just FYI: https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/